# Return user profile with the post Web API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing a web api for a social media app. I retrieve a single post data in my Post class

```
public class Post
{
    public int postId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string postAuthor { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(4000, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string postText { get; set; }

    public int postPrivacy { get; set; }

    public string dateEdited { get; set; }

 }
}
```

I need to retrieve the author image within the same query but the author image field is in the author class, should I add a field for the image? Or how can I solve this?

Comment: You need to provide more context for this question i.e. code for your `Author` class, how you are storing your data etc.

Comment: Yes you need to add a field for the image. To post the image, the image object should be converted in bytes and serialize/deserialize it.

Comment: I only store the image name, it is a string field